# How do we add and save additional parameters to a serializer object in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication, django-serializer

These are the field in my PostSerializer

```
fields = ('id','user_id','title','desc','comments')
```

The `user_id` and `comments` are code generated and `title`,`desc` were obtained from api calls. I want to pass this as additional values to my `request.data`. This is my APIView object

```
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    def post(self,request):
        request.data['user_id'] = request.user.id
        request.data['comments'] = "machine generated"
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if post_serializer.is_valid():
            post_serializer.save()
            print(request.data)
            return Response(post_serializer.data)
```

While my `print(request.data)` shows `user_id`,`comments` fields and their corresponding values. In the saved database though the values for `user_id` and `comments` are `null`.

How do we add and save additional parameters to a serializer object in django rest framework?

Comment: Share your PostSerialier and Model code too, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**
You can pass additional fields to `serializer.save()` as follows:

```py
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    def post(self,request):
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if post_serializer.is_valid():
            post_serializer.save (
            
            user_id=request.user_id,
            comments="machine generated"
            
            )
            return Response(post_serializer.data)
```

But through this method, you should make `blank=True` for `user_id`, `comments` to make serializer valid.
**Method 2**
I'm not sure this method works correctly, but i recommend you to not change `request.data`.
first copy that and then make changes to new dictionary. as follows:

```py
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    def post(self,request):
        data = dict(request.data)
        data['user_id'] = request.user.id
        data['comments'] = "machine generated"

        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=data)
        if post_serializer.is_valid():
            post_serializer.save()
            return Response(post_serializer.data)
```

**Method 3**
You can change `request.data` with `.update()` method without losing data from client side:

```py
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    def post(self,request):
        request.data.update ( {

            'user_id': request.user.id,
            'comments': "machine generated text"

        } )

        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if post_serializer.is_valid():
            post_serializer.save()
            print(request.data)
            return Response(post_serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thank you, method1 works but  method2 and method3 does not. Can you please tell what is the reason for the failure of my method.

Comment: I'm not sure about it. If i had your PostSerializer and Post model, maybe i could help you.